# how to change version of gcc to the old version? i don't know

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

how can I pass to a specific version of gcc in ubuntu? I need the 4.3 and I have the 4.8,
I tried to install simply the 4.3 but doesn't work.

Comment: What commands did you try using to uninstall/install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc is a symbolic link in /usr/bin which points to /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 
if you have gcc-4.3 installed, you simply can delete the old symlink and make a new one:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.3 /usr/bin/gcc
```